# Best practice when using dot and bracket notation

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var name = ui.item.label.split('. ', 2);
name.lastname  = name[0];
name.firstname = name[1];
```

The `split()` method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array. However, I want to reference the array associatively. So, I re-assigned name as shown above.

Did I just add two more elements to the name array or say are `name[0]` and `name.lastname` the same element?

If I'm correct I created the following array of length 4...

```
name.0
name.1
name.lastname
name.firstname
```

Comment: The body of your question doesn't mention a "best practice" or ask for advice. You may want to edit your title to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added two more properties to the array object, but not numeric indices. It's not an "array of length 4", it's an "array of length 2, with two custom properties on it".

```
var a = "foo bar".split(' ');

console.log(a)
//-> ["foo", "bar"]

console.log(a.length);
//-> 2

a.first  = a[0];
a.second = a[1];
console.log(a.length);
//-> 2

console.log( Object.keys(a) );
//-> ["0", "1", "first", "second"]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused... so are you saying i have something like the following: {name:[value, value], lastname:value, firstname:value} ?

Comment: @NelsonM Arrays in JavaScript are a kind of object, but not the same as the objects you get with curly-bracket literal notation (`{...}`). Every object in JavaScript can have custom properties added to it (even functions!). If you're asking about implementation details of how this is stored, that varies based on the browser/engine, and is also largely unimportant to the novice scripter.

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing that up. so name[0], name[1], name.lastname and name.firstname can all have different values. But since the keys for the elements one and two is numeric, i have to reference them as name[0] and name[1] and not name.0 or name.1- correct?

Comment: The only reason you have to refer to them like that is syntax. Since they're not valid identifiers you must use square bracket notation to access those properties. You could similarly access `name["firstname"]` and `name["1"]`. As all object properties are strings, the dot notation is just a convenience, as is the fact that `foo[0]` is the same as `foo["0"]`.